# Console from a Runtime.getRuntime().exec after program end?

Tags: java, unix, ubuntu, runtime.exec

I'm building a restarter for my litte program.

The basic idea is to run a process using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`, that excecutes the program itself, then running `System.exit(0);`

this is the code that does the restarting:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strList);  
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

// exit
System.exit(0);
```

Where `strList` is an `String[]` that is something like:

```
  {"/bin/bash","-c","java -jar path/to.jar"}
```

Don't worry about OS portability, the program will be run exclusively on Ubuntu.

The program restarts fine, or at least a new process is running (and continuing to restart itself after a while)

The problem is after restart I loose the console, so i have no idea what is actually happening with the program.

**Is there any way to start the new process in "the same window" or any way to access it (maybe by using screen?)?**

Comment: I would go for a more solid solution, which is to build your application this way that it doesn't need to be restarted.

Comment: Its more about reducing maintence and ease updating

Comment: This is a duplicate question.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597927/how-to-open-a-command-terminal-in-linux

Comment: I suggest you use http://upstart.ubuntu.com/ instead of doing this with Java

Comment: You're losing focus in your terminal because you started a new instance. I don't think there is a clean way to attach the fork to the same terminal session.