# Executing screen command from Java

Tags: java, linux, sh, gnu-screen

I am using the following code to execute an SH file in Linux

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c", file.getPath() });
```

This code works however I can't use the screen command in the SH file when executing it from Java, I get this error

> Must be connected to a terminal.

So is it possible to "connect" java to a terminal? I would like to be able to also view this screen when I connect via SSH so I think it has to be connected to the terminal that is shown when you SSH into the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597927/how-to-open-a-command-terminal-in-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I use `screen -dm` it will work. Thanks!