# Open Terminal Window using Java

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I want to know how to open the Linux Terminal in a Java app.

Further explanation: I have a java app. There is a button inside my java app. When you click that button, the Linux Terminal must pop open. I won't run or do anything on the Terminal, I just want to open it.

I've been searching for few hours but found none that suites what I want to do.

Please write the code itself and don't answer by giving links like "this may help".

Comment: Can we see your code please?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is about helping with specific programming issues.  It is not a place that provides 'Code-on-demand.'

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher.. I'm asking how to open the terminal in java so obviously codes are the answer

Comment: @JunedAhsan.. As I mentioned, I haven't found the right codes to open the terminal so no codes yet. As for the java, I can't disclose the java codes so you can imagine the codes of a button with an action listener.

Answer (score 3):

you can  do something like this:

```
try {
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
String myScript = .....
String[] cmdArray = {"xterm", "-e", myScript + " ; le_exec"};
r.exec(cmdArray).waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what to put in myScript.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597927/how-to-open-a-command-terminal-in-linux)

```
import java.io.*;

class TerminalLauncher
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String command= "/usr/bin/xterm"; 
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();  
        Process pr = rt.exec(command);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it gives this error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/xterm": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: the path may vary . please check the other post

Comment: tried using only "xterm" as suggested by the other post. still the same error

Comment: what is the desktop you have installed on ur linux ? Gnome? KDE ?

Comment: hello it works but whenever I want to use pr.destroy() or other possible functions it's giving me null pointer exception. Please advice

Comment: can u show me your snippet of code?