# Simple way to run java classfile (Terminal)

Tags: java, linux, windows, terminal, minecraft

I wanted to put a java classfile up for download recently, which people could run in Terminal. It's a Minecraft command generator, so the people downloading it won't necessarily have the greatest mental capacity (I'm referring to 8-year-olds who have no idea what they're doing, of course).

Anyway, I wanted to provide a **simple, single** command, both for the Mac / Linux terminal and the Windows command line, that ran the classfile without any complications. The problem is, I don't want to execute it by doing `/cd path`, and then doing `java someFolder.someClass`. I just want to have a single command to open the file. If anyone could provide these commands for me, both in Mac / Linux and Windows, that would be great.

Sorry for the super long explanation :P

Comment: you can write a script in sh and cmd versions and make it executable like run.sh and run.cmd, a lot of standalone java applications work like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jar file with a main class in the manifest would probably be the easiest thing. Then the command is `java -jar myjarfile.jar`.

A swing application would probably be easier as the default way of running executable jars doesn't open a command prompt (it uses `javaw` instead of `java`).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first start a terminal and then run java in that terminal, which can be a bit tricky.

[How to open a command terminal in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597927/how-to-open-a-command-terminal-in-linux)

Why not create an interface (Swing) and pack everything in a jar?

Comment: And with this you could also get a jar wrapper.